# salesforce send email by url /_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor

Tags: email, salesforce-id, urlhacking

I need to send emails in salesforce through URL`/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid={!Purchase_Order__c.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id}&template_id=00X70000001GUTz`. I know that the parameter returnURL specifies the url when you click "cancel" button of the email sending page. Is there a way to control the url after you click "Send"?

Although I set the "p3_lkid" as a ID of purchase order object, I want to go to the opportunity page after sending the email.